# Encoded string compression algorithm in C/C++

Tags: c

I am searching for an algorithm to compare two strings efficiently without occupying much memory and in less time. So what I am currently doing is, compressing character string first and then comparing both compressed string(to avoid memory errors. as string could be very long here)

String contains characters from set [0-9],x,o,X.

Now compression rule is like only certain repetitive tokens need to be compressed. For example:
'o' is end of token and it comes always at end of sequence of one or more digits(0-9},'x' is to show multiplication etc.

Examples:
1. 8o8o80 should be compressed as 3x80
2. 8oXXXX should be compressed as 804xX
3. 64o8o8o16o16o should be 64o2x8o2x16o etc..

I wonder if is there any existing algorithms for such compression strings?

Will appreciate any kind of help to sort this out. Thanks!!

Comment: How can compressing and then comparing be faster than just comparing?

Comment: what is wrong with a naive compare? It doesn't use any more memory than that is already used by the two strings, and could be faster (potentially more accurate)...

Comment: @Jon: not faster but memory efficient as I was getting out of memory error for uncompressed string.

Comment: what if you just compare the two hashes of the strings? not faster than simply comparing the strings, though.

Comment: the strange thing is that you have two strings already **in memory**, comparing don't consume much memory if done byte-by-byte. the question is not very clear.

Comment: @Nim: Naive compare won't be helpful here. As i said 2x8o should be equal to 8o8o as logically both mean same.(Imagine 1000 tokens repetitive with/without compression). So I want to have similar encoding for both and then naive compare would work fine.

Comment: @vulkanino: Right, let me clarify this. I am storing many strings in memory and then start comparison. So just to save memory I am compressing the string and then applying normal comparison(byte by byte). But as I asked how do I compress strings?

Comment: @Raj: The problem is that you are storing *many* strings *in memory* and then comparing. It sounds like you should not pre-process all of them and/or not buffer them in memory. If your code should do this but does not, compression will not fix your problem but merely postpone the day of reckoning.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [run length encoding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).
You find some implementations [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: yes, but he has a strange "terminator" character, so he might need to modify the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks stacker. But in default implementation of RLE, token is a char but for me its set of char. And also there is no notion of terminating char in that algo.

Comment: I am not able to find any suitable compression algorithm meeting my expectation. So I am going to implement one which works for me.